# jq: missing JSON object detection

Tags: json, jq

My JSON data:

```
{
  "Tags": [
           {  "Key": "Team",     "Value": "AA" },
           {  "Key": "Division", "Value": "BB" },
           {  "Key": "Name",     "Value": "CC" }
        ]
}
```

I'd like to display value of Name ("CC" in example above).
If this value is missing "N/A" should be displayed.
What I'm looking for is pure jq replacement of this jq and bash mix:

```
a=$( cat json | jq -r '.Tags[] | select( .Key=="Name" ) | .Value' );
if [ -z $a ]; then a="N/A"; fi
echo $a
```

Comment: your JSON data is invalid, Tags should be a string "Tags"

Answer (score 2):

Here is the perfect solution from David Tolnay:

https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/976

Quoting it here:

Try this:

```
jq -r '.Tags | from_entries | .Name // "N/A"'
```

This converts the list of key/value pairs to a map using from_entries, then picks out the "Name" in the map. Then it uses the "alternative operator" // to produce "N/A" if Name was not in the map.

This requires jq 1.5 in order to understand capitalized "Key" and "Value" in from_entries. If you are stuck on jq 1.4 or older, you need to explicitly convert them to lowercase:

```
jq -r '.Tags | map({key:.Key, value:.Value}) | from_entries | .Name // "N/A"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the alternative operator, `//`.

`jq -r '.Tags[] | select(.Key == "Name") | .Value // "N/A"'`